# Javascript: display text in several steps

Tags: javascript

I want to load large amounts of text. In pseudo-code, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
var first = "Some text"
print first
var second = "Some more text"
print second
```

as opposed to:

```
var first = "Some text"
var second = "Some more text"
print first + second
```

I have tried using

```
$(window).load(function(){}
```

But this only works if I put in something that causes the page to get drawn/flushed before it continues. For instance an alert() before doing anything else in load will create the desired behavior. Otherwise, all is printed at the same time.

Any ideas?

P.S. I am not looking to load lazy. I want the whole thing to load, but printing intermediate results to the screen.

Edit 1: added counter example

Comment: What size of text you are trying to load ?

Comment: @RakeshChouhan The first string is a couple of sentences. The second string is 500k+ characters.

Comment: Are you thinking about something like a millisec timer and each tot millisec It prints a character, to simulate an "animated digited text"?

Comment: On serverside, one could flush and sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this effect by using `setTimeout`.

Example (based on your pseudo-code):

```
const first = "Some text"
print first
setTimeout(() => {
    const second = "Some more text"
    print second
})
```

If you have more than 2 steps, consider using promises (to avoid wide indentations):

```
const first = "Some text"
print first
new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    const second = "Some more text (1)"
    print second
    resolve()
})).then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    const third = "Some more text (2)"
    print third
    resolve()
}))).then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    const fourth = "Some more text (3)"
    print fourth
    resolve()
})))
```

Or even `async/await`:

```
async function printTexts() {
    const texts = ["Some text", "Some more text (1)", "Some more text (2)", "Some more text (3)"]
    for(const text of texts) {
        print text
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))
    }
}
printTexts()
```

Comment: i would place print text inside the loop directly, not in the timeout.